# Blending / Lerping between textures in a Unity CG Shader

Tags: unity, shaders, textures, lerp

I can lerp between colors just fine, but lerping between textures just doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
 Shader "Custom/Terrain1"
    {
        Properties
        {
            _RockInnerShallow ("Rock Inner Shallow", 2D) = "white" {}
            _RockInnerDeep ("Rock Inner Deep", 2D) = "white" {}
            _RockLight ("Rock Light", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
            _RockDark ("Rock Dark", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
            _GrassLight ("Grass Light", 2D) = "white" {}
            _GrassDark ("Grass Dark", 2D) = "white" {}
    

        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _Blend ("Texture Blend", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
        _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Glossiness ("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _Test ("Test", Float) = 0.0

        _NoiseTex("Noise Texture", 2D) = "White" {}
    }


 void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o)
    {
fixed4 c  = lerp(tex2D (_RockInnerShallow, IN.uv_RockInnerShallow),
                 tex2D (_RockInnerDeep, IN.uv_RockInnerDeep), rockDepthT) * _Color;

   o.Albedo = c.rgb;
   o.Alpha = c.a;
```

This last bit is the lerping part.

Comment: This looks very similar to [your previous question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/194854/39518) — did you mean to edit and clarify the existing question, instead of posting a new one? Note that making substantial constructive edits bumps the question up in the feed, so it gains visibility just like a new question, just without leaving dead ends as land mines for future searchers.

Comment: Can you clarify what output this shader produces, and how that differs from what you want?